# Performance testing through jmeter for Oauth0 login

Tags: regex, oauth, jmeter, performance-testing

I am new to performance testing, doing it through Jmeter for my application.

I have recorded the script through blazemeter and running it in Jmeter, but it is failing at authentication step. My application uses OAuth0 to manage authentication.

How can I do performance testing on such application, will regex extractor help my case?

Can anyone please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can record and replay, you need to [**create the signature**](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html), the exact steps will differ depending on your server implementation as there could be different algorithms in scope.

You need to obtain the documentation or contact application developers with regards to how to properly create the signature.

If you're lucky enough you can use [OAuth Java client library](https://oauth.net/code/) for your OAuth provider from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) in order to sign the request.

Check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for more details on how to bypass OAuth login challenge in JMeter tests.